# How to get Last Message from chat conversation?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hi i have a table name `messages` i want to get last message from chat conversation between two users.

Table -

```
id  from_id   to_id    text     created
========================================
1      1        2     hi        2014-12-01 10:30:10
2      2        1     Hello     2014-12-01 10:30:20
3      3        1     Hi chinu  2014-12-01 10:32:02
4      3        1     hw r u?   2014-12-01 10:32:22
5      2        1     h r u?    2014-12-01 10:33:01
```

Please check my query =

```
//$user_id=$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
$user_id=1;
$fields=array('DISTINCT(Message.from_id), Message.id, Message.text, Message.created');

    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'conditions'=>array('Message.to_id'=>$user_id),
            'limit' => 30,
            'order' => array(
                'Message.created' => 'DESC',
                'Message.id' => 'DESC'
            ),
            'fields'=>$fields,
            'group'=>array('Message.from_id')
    );
    $inbox = $this->Paginator->paginate('Message');
    pr($inbox);
    $this->set('inbox', $inbox);
```

I want to get last message conversation between 2 and 3 id. The output looks like -

```
id  from_id   to_id    text     created
========================================
5      2        1     h r u?    2014-12-01 10:33:01
4      3        1     hw r u?   2014-12-01 10:32:22
```

Please help me. If you don't know the cakephp please post core php MySQL query here.

Thanks
chatfun

Comment: The expected output does not look like `between 2 and 3` and looks like `between 2 and 1` and `3 and 1`

Comment: Yes but i don't want listed my own id

Comment: Add `WHERE` clause `WHERE Message.from_id <> $user_id`

Comment: Are you looking for the last message between the conversation between the users 2 & 3? Or are you looking for the last message sent to user 1? Or are you looking for the last messages sent to user 1 for every conversation that user 1 is part of?

Comment: so are you looking at the last conversation from each `from_id` ?

Comment: Yes @AbhikChakraborty you are right

Comment: @AgRizzo its not matter some one msg to me or me msg to someone. I want to get last message between two users each. Please check facebook messages you will get my question answer. https://www.facebook.com/messages/

Comment: I dont know cake-php but I can provide sql you need to convert that to cake-php

Comment: Ok @AbhikChakraborty you may answer in core-php i will convert it to cakephp query format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this query -

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM messages WHERE (from_id=1 OR to_id=1) ORDER BY created DESC) as m GROUP BY `from_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this query would work (although I don't understand why 'to_id' = 1 in your expected output, maybe I didn't get your purpose right)

```
SELECT 'id', 'from_id', 'to_id', 'text', 'created'
FROM Message
WHERE ('from_id' = 2 AND 'to_id' = 3) OR ('from_id' = 3 AND 'to_id' = 2)
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You have just using static id `2` and `3`. Suppose i have chat with 1000 more people. Then what should i do?

Comment: @Chatfun your question says the latest conversation between two users. If that is not what you are looking for, please edit the question.

Comment: Yes i want to get all last messages group by users conversation.

Comment: Can you please check left side users in facebook messages you will know what i want. - https://www.facebook.com/messages/

Answer (score 0):

This how the query looks like to achieve what you are looking at , i.e. getting the last conversation from each `from_id`

```
select t1.* from Message 
t1 left join Message t2  
on t1.from_id = t2.from_id 
and t1.id<t2.id where t2.id is null;
```

You have a primary key `id` auto_incremented so it could be used in the comparison instead of date.

Or

```
select t1.* from Message t1 
where not exists (
select 1 from Message t2 where t1.from_id = t2.from_id and t1.id < t2.id
);
```